# How do I show that this function has an antiderivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have the following problem:

> Let $f$ be an analytic function on $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. I want to show that there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)-\frac{\lambda}{z}$ has an antiderivative.

I first remarked that $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{\lambda}{z}$ is analytic on $\Omega=\{z:0<|z|\}$. Hence it has a Laurent series expansion. Now I thought that maybe we could take $\lambda=a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion. But somehow I don't see how to integrate this because I thought if $\int \frac{\lambda}{z}dz=0$ then I would be done because then the integral is always the same.

Could maybe someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I thought that maybe we could take $\lambda=a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series expansion.

You should let $\lambda$ be the $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$, not $g$. Write
$$
f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{-n}z^{-n}
$$
and let $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{\lambda}{z}$ with $\lambda=a_{-1}$. Then

$$
g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{-n}z^{-n},\quad |z|>0\;.
$$
Observe that $1/z$ is not in the expansion of $g(z)$ and it has an antiderivative in the punctured disk, namely
$$
G(z):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{-n}\frac{1}{(1-n)z^{n-1}}
$$

Term by term differentiation can be justified by the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration) of power series.

Comment: @aprozz: The indices $n$ are nothing but dummy variables. Writing a few terms out explicitly, you will see what is really going on.